# Compressing CSV files in R

Tags: r, csv, compression, gzip

I hope all is well. I am struggling to compress CSV files in R. I have a 14 GB CSV file that needs to be compressed a lot so that I may share it with colleagues. Here is the code I have in R so far...

write_csv(file_name,gzfile('file_name.csv.gz'))

Is there something else I am missing? Also what will be the size of the new compressed file? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You are quite close.

```
library(readr)
write_csv( your.data, "somefile.csv.gz" )
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response, I am running this now.